# Jupyter notebook abre en modo texto

Tags: jupyter, julia

He instalado Julia sobre Ubuntu 22.04, cuando ejecuto jupyter notebook, me muestra los ficheros .jl, pero cuando abro alguno de ellos se abren en modo texto y no con el formato de notebook.
He creado un notebook nuevo, selecciono el motor y todo ok, pero lo guarda como .ipynb. Parece ser que jupyter reconoce solo .ipynb y no .jl.

Que puedo hacer para que .jl sea el default.

Gracias

Comment: El formato de notebook lo da el formato de archivo ipynb. Hay plugins para moverse de un lado a otro pero no es transparente https://github.com/JunoLab/Weave.jl